# Taking too much time when I run sql batch file through command line than when executing (importing) using SQL Yog

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

Taking too much time when I run sql batch file through command line (e.g., mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uroot -proot testing_besql < D:/Apache2/htdocs/db.sql my batch file taking around 2 minutes 30 seconds) than when executing (importing) using SQL Yog (Only taking around 30 seconds). Any way to improve command line speed.

Comment: Use [mysqlimport](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlimport.html).

Comment: I am importing a whole database not a single table

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the sql file add
    SET autocommit=0;
And at the bottom of the file add
    COMMIT;

This will bring in the speed of SQL yog db import to the import through command line